# Is there a way to check if SQL SP is running or completed?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I use Misrosoft SQL Server Management Studio to work with databases. I manually started SP execution on PC One. Is there any way to check if SP is still running or not from a different PC?

Comment: If you know the SPID you can use `sp_who <spid>` to see if there's any activity

Comment: Alternatively you can search by loginname `sp_who 'gvee\george'`

Comment: YES! sp_who does the job pretty well. Thanks a lot. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it ;)

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure if I hurried up or no. Will give it some testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system stored procedure `sp_who` might be of use: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx

If you know the SPID then you can use

```
EXEC sp_who <spid>;
```

Alternatively you can use the *login name* of the login that executed the command

```
EXEC sp_who 'george\gvee';
```

If the **cmd** column states `AWAITING COMMAND` then this indicates that that session is not performing a query or other action i.e. it is idle

Comment: Hmm. It always gives me status=runnable and hostname=my_local_pc. tried to execute on databases for which: SP is executing, SP executed from another host and finished; idle - always the same output.

Comment: @AlexanderZhak note that the hostname is the machine from which the command was executed. If it is showing your local PC then that suggests that the spid is on your PC. Open the link I posted and look at the **status** column values. Note that "sleeping" is missing from the list but is relatively self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQL Server Profiler`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use a free tool like [**Idera SQL Check**](http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/freetools/sqlcheck). Shows graphically a lot of statatiscs about the SQL Server current state.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I'm lacking permissions to gather stats